# Pip 7.0.1 not installing included files from package

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I have a python package as a .tar.gz. I have been using pip 6.1.1 without error for sometime. When installing the package, `pip install mypackage.tar.gz`, distutils ensure that certain files in the package are put into this `/var/www/myfolder` location.

Pip 6.1.1 and Pip 1.2.1 follow this behaviorcorrectly, however pip 7.0.1 does not. Pip 7.0.1 does not move the files in the "myfolder" directory at all.

At first I though its was a distutils issue, however now that I realize the only scenario in which mypackage.tar.gz does not move files into the `/var/www/myfolder` location is when it is installed by pip withversion 7.0.1 I conclude its a pip issue.

I haven't found anything of significance in the change docs between the version of pip, but I'm not sure what I may be looking for.

Any idea what could be happening?

Note it is not a permissions issue as I run the pip commands with sudo.

Comment: `pip` is at 7.1.2 now, have you tried that?

Comment: Can you show your `setup.py` and related package configuration files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with version 7.0.0 pip builds wheels from sdists and installs these wheels instead of installing directly from sdists. There's a known difference in where *data_files* are installed between installing from wheel and from sdist. Citing from [*Packaging and Distributing Projects*](https://packaging.python.org/distributing/#data-files):

> setuptools allows absolute “data_files” paths, and pip honors them as
>   absolute, when installing from sdist. This is not true when installing
>   from wheel distributions. Wheels don’t support absolute paths, and
>   they end up being installed relative to “site-packages”. For
>   discussion see [wheel Issue #92](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/wheel/issues/92).

See also:

*Wheel* issue 92: [bdist_wheel makes absolute data_files relative to site-packages](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/wheel/issues/92)
*PyPI Metadata Formats* issue 13: [Add a new subdirectory to allow wheels to bypass installation schemes](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pypi-metadata-formats/issues/13/)
*Python Packaging User Guide* pull 212: [Fix section on data_files](https://github.com/pypa/python-packaging-user-guide/pull/212)
Presentation by Ionel Cristian Mărieș - [Less known packaging features and tricks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-UbWsO9rZk)

Comment: Is there a way to get the user's intended behavior?

Comment: @aryamccarthy None that I know of. There's a work to make it possible at https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pypi-metadata-formats/issues/13/